# Cognos - Get a Text 'Continued' every time the list breaks to a new page

Tags: cognos, cognos-10, cognos-bi

I have a report with multiple lists in a single page. The output of the report is in PDF and the user wants an indicator like 'Continued' every time any of the list breaks from one page and goes to a new page. They don't want to set the pagination to 'Do not allow Data to a new page' as it disturbs the font.

Is there a way to get the txt every time the list section breaks??